# How to write common utility function in angular ts file. I have code below like this. I want to merge both function into one

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML file:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedSrcLocFlexItems.length">
        <div *ngFor="let item of selectedSrcLocFlexItems; "
          class="dropdown-tags mt-2 p-1 px-2 d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          {{item}}
          <button class="smart-icon-close smart-btn btn" (click)="removeSourceLocationItem(item)"
            aria-label="close button" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedwrkLocFlexItems.length">
        <div *ngFor="let item of selectedwrkLocFlexItems; "
          class="dropdown-tags mt-2 p-1 px-2 d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          {{item}}
          <button class="smart-icon-close smart-btn btn" (click)="removeWorkLocationItem(item)"
            aria-label="close button" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
```

Ts file:

```
removeWorkLocationItem(item: any): void {
    this.selectedWrkLocFlexItems = this.selectedWrkLocFlexItems.filter(t => t !== item);
  }

  removeSourceLocationItem(item: any): void {
    this.selectedSrcLocFlexItems = this.selectedSrcLocFlexItems.filter(t => t !== item);
  }
```

Expected:
want to have common function for both removeWorkLocationItem,removeSourceLocationItem and result need to reflected in ui.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `removeWorkLocationItem` and `removeSourceLocationItem` by a generic `removeItem` function:

```js
removeItem(myArray: [], item: any): any {
  if (Array.isArray(myArray) && myArray.length > 0) {
    const idx = myArray.findIndex((i) => i === item);
    idx > -1 && myArray.splice(idx, 1);
  }
}
// Note: splice changes the original array
```

Use the new `removeItem` function in the buttons click passing the array as a parameter:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedSrcLocFlexItems.length">
  <div
    *ngFor="let item of selectedSrcLocFlexItems"
    class="dropdown-tags mt-2 p-1 px-2 d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
  >
    {{ item }}
    <button
      class="smart-icon-close smart-btn btn"
      (click)="removeItem(selectedSrcLocFlexItems, item)"
      aria-label="close button"
      type="button"
    ></button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedwrkLocFlexItems.length">
  <div
    *ngFor="let item of selectedwrkLocFlexItems"
    class="dropdown-tags mt-2 p-1 px-2 d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
  >
    {{ item }}
    <button
      class="smart-icon-close smart-btn btn"
      (click)="removeItem(selectedwrkLocFlexItems, item)"
      aria-label="close button"
      type="button"
    ></button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

The view will reflect the changes, since Angular will run a change detection after button was clicked!